# xkb rebind Capslock + shift + hjkl to same behaviour as arrowkeys + shift

Tags: linux, x11, xkb

A long time ago I rebound my capslock + hjkl to essentially work as if they were arrow keys in the xkb config file.

```
    key <CAPS>  { [ ISO_Level5_Shift,   ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift] };

    key <AC06> { [               h,               H,           U1E9E,        NoSymbol,           Left,           Left,           Left,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AC07> { [               j,               J,    dead_cedilla,        NoSymbol,           Down,           KP_Down,           KP_Down,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AC08> { [               k,               K, dead_belowcomma,        NoSymbol,             Up,            KP_Up,               KP_Up,        NoSymbol ] };
    key <AC09> { [               l,               L,     dead_ogonek,        NoSymbol,          Right,         KP_Right,           KP_Right,        NoSymbol ] };
```

I could never however figure out how to set the behavior of capslock + shift + hjkl  to work the same way as capslock + shift + arrowkeys would. So that the text would get highlighted.

How would one go about doing that?

Comment: Is that really syntactically correct Xkb? As far as I remember, it only allows four levels per line, not eight. Aren't you mixing it with Xmodmap?

Comment: No worries, it is. It's a german layout. You get altgr as a new modifier and you can combine it with the other ones so it makes 8 levels possible.

Comment: @Vlad did you solve this? I'd be interested in the solution.